# Problem with instalation of LucidDB

Tags: database, installation, java, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to install LucidDB on Ubuntu 10.04 64Bits.

In the doc they say :

> Set the JAVA_HOME using the correct
>   location for your JRE (make sure it's
>   Java 1.6 or higher), and then
>   re-login:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/j2sdk
```

I just set my JAVA_HOME to my jre path : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre`

But at the end the installation still fails. Someone would know why ?

This is the stacktrace I get :

```
# Tracing configuration

handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=$TRACE_DIR/Trace.log

.level=CONFIG
E    OF

LOCALCLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
for lib in `find $LIB_DIR -path $LIB_DIR/plugin -not -prune -o -name "*.jar"`; do
  LOCALCLASSPATH=$LOCALCLASSPATH:$lib
done

cygwin=false
case "`uname`" in
    CYWGIN*) cygwin=true ;;
esac

if $cygwin; then
    LOCALCLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --windows "$LOCALCLASSPATH"`
fi

echo $LOCALCLASSPATH >$BIN_DIR/classpath.gen
```

Answer (score 1):

Your installation was successful it appears.  That's just the echo'ing of the LucidDB install.bat.
According to the getting started guide:

http://pub.eigenbase.org/wiki/LucidDbGettingStarted
`If you didn't set JAVA_HOME correctly, you should get a corresponding error message. Otherwise, if all goes well, you'll see a lot of script output, ending with the following line:

echo $LOCALCLASSPATH >$BIN_DIR/classpath.gen`